# The value of regex match groups remain empty

Tags: c#, regex

i need to extract width and height values from a very long xaml string. 
What i would like to do:
I want to match the part that has the values with a regular expression and the match to already have the values in separate groups, so i don't have to parse the string anymore.
My regex looks like this:

```
Match pagesizes = Regex.Match(str, "SomeElement\\S\\s\\S+(?<width>\\d+)\\S\\s\\S+(?<height>\\d+)");
```

while the string looks like this (that's just a small part of the whole string):

```
Uniform\" Name=\"view\"><av:Canvas Name=\"SomeElement\" Width=\"2100\" Height=\"2970\"><av:Line X1=\"0\" Y1=\"1485\" X2=\"150\" Y2=\"1485\" Stroke=\"#FF000000\" StrokeThickness=\"1\" Name=\"holepunchline\" /><av:TextBlock Text=\"programname\" FontSize=\"30\" Foreground=\"#FF808080\" Name=\"text\" av:Canvas.Left=\"160\" av:Canvas.Bottom=\"100\"><av:TextBlock.LayoutTransform><av:RotateTransform Angle=\"-90\" /></av:TextBlock.LayoutTransform></av:TextBlock><av:Grid Name=\"grid\" Width=\"1850\" Height=\"2720\"
```

Pagesize contains the string i want and has three groups. But the groups width and height remain empty. I'm fairly inexperienced in using regular expressions. Where is my error?

Comment: You are using `\S+` that is greedy, you may use `@"SomeElement\S\s\S+?(?<width>\d+)\S\s\S+?(?<height>\d+)"`, but since it is XML, you should just parse it with XML parser.

Comment: The questionmark helped. Thx. The string itself is actually a WPF object i serialized with XamlWriter. Now i want to make a WPF element from the serialized string again, but these sizes i need are not being set corectly. That's why i need to get them this way.